# How to fix bonded neutral and ground in subpanels

Tags: grounding, subpanel, neutral

I am selling my home and the buyers inspection says the bonded neutral and ground must be corrected. How should I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Cost estimates are not valid question topics since what may apply to your case has little relevance to others.

Comment: Normally it's not  a hard fix just get an other bus bar (a few $ at HD), drill a couple of holes in the back of the panel at a convenient location, install the bus bar with a couple of self tapping screws and move all the grounds (bare or green) to it, then remove the bonding wire or screw between the neutral and ground.   BUT and I hate to say it, you have a bigger issue here.   It looks like you only have 3 wire service to the subpanel. You need 2 hots, neutral and a ground.  Is it practical to run new cables to these subs?  Are they in the same building as the main panel?

Comment: If a seperate earth ground wire is not allowed is to see if you can offer some discount and let the buyer purchase it as is. Not know the layout and other details I cannot give you a more definitive suggestion.

Comment: Are these **both** subpanels? Or is one a subpanel and the other the main panel?

Comment: I agree with manassehkatz those both are subs the grounds should be connected to the box these lol pre-1999 when 4 wire was not required and depending on the date no ground rod was required home inspectors are often wrong and the code enforce at the time of the installation is what matters. Pre 99 build the inspector is wrong!

Comment: Can you get us close-up shots of the insides of both panels please?

Answer (score 1):

### Retrofitting ground is allowed

So all  you really need to do is obtain accessory ground bars for the subpanel(s)... then...

- Option 1:  Install common Romex cable clamps in knockouts in each panel. And then run #4 bare copper ground wire from one ground bar, through the cable clamp out of the panel, through the other cable clamp into the other panel, and to its ground bar.  Make sure you are sure of your lengths before you buy the expensive copper wire. ***Option 2: don't do this and see below***.
- Move the branch circuit ground wires to it, so they are no longer on the neutral bar.
- Remove any neutral-ground bonding straps or screws in the subpanel.

### Alternate plan: For panels right next to each other, fit a *conduit box spacer*

Anytime I have 2 panels right next to each other, I like to line up at least one of the "knockouts" and fit a short bit of metal conduit between them.  I normally use EMT or Rigid, but with panels *this* close, use a metal conduit box spacer.

[image]

The "official" reason to do that is to allow pass-through of wires (should that need ever arise).    However the "unofficial" side-effect is that it connects the two panels with metal conduit.  **Metal conduit is a valid grounding path, so there is no need for a  ground *wire***.

So your $1 conduit box spacer can do the job of $10 of fat copper wire.

You would need to unbolt one of the panels enough that it can move about 1  inch.  It's OK if it still hangs on one screw and pivots, as long as you can find some knockouts that line up.

I strongly prefer to install 2 or more of these, for "belt and suspenders" reliability.

Comment: It looks to me like **both** are subpanels (asking OP to find out for sure). If they are both subpanels then still need a ground back to the main.

Comment: We also need to know if they are in the same structure or a detached structure.  If detached, there are additional grounding requirements...like a couple of ground rods.